# android Bluetooth Pairing request

Tags: android, bluetooth

Could you help me? How could I check if user denyed bluetooth pairing request?

Answer (score 5):

As soon as the user press Cancel on the Bluetooth Pairing Request Screen,

intent with action

> android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED

is fired, and inside it, bundle with int key

> android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE

has value

> android.bluetooth BluetoothDevice.BONE_NONE

For example, after registering broadcast receiver for the action, get int value like below.
Then you will know if user pressed cancel on the pairing screen.

```
if (intent.getExtras().getInt(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE) == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't easily right now.  Because the platform hides this from you the only option is to check the bonded devices list before and after